# Why is my nested grid-container not creating equal width columns?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

so I am new to CSS grids and I've been toying around with it. I'm trying to see if I can match the layout of this mock-up in a general sense with some experimental code I've been writing: https://ibb.co/GFYqMRx

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body class="body">


    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="side-navigation">Side Navigation</div>

    <main class="main">
      <div class="item search">Search</div>
      <div class="item traffic">Traffic</div>
      <div class="item daily-traffic">Daily Traffic </div>
      <div class="item mobile-users">Mobile Users</div>
      <div class="item social-stats">Social Stats</div>
      <div class="item new-members">New Members</div>
      <div class="item recent-activity">Recent Activity</div>
      <div class="item message-user">Message User</div>
      <div class="item settings">Settings</div>
    </main>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.item {
  border: 1px red solid;
}

.header {
  background-color: purple;
  grid-area: header;
}
.side-navigation {
  background-color: orange;
  grid-area: side-navigation;
}
.main {
  background-color: grey;
  grid-area: main;
}

.search {
  grid-area: search;
}
.traffic {
  grid-area: traffic;
}
.daily-traffic {
  grid-area: daily-traffic;
}
.mobile-users {
  grid-area: mobile-users;
}
.social-stats {
  grid-area: social-stats;
}
.new-members {
  grid-area: new-members;
}
.recent-activity {
  grid-area: recent-activity;
}
.message-user {
  grid-area: message-user;
}
.settings {
  grid-area: settings;
}
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 80px 80px 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "header"
  "side-navigation"
  "main";
}


@media (min-width: 769px) {

  body {
    grid-template-columns: 80px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
    "header header"
    "side-navigation main"
  }
  .main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: 150px;
  } 
}
```

I was first able to create the desired layout by manipulating grid lines, but I wanted to see if I could do the same thing by solely utilizing the grid-template-areas property.

For screen sizes greater than 769px, I split the nested main container into two columns, 1fr each, but I ended up getting some weird effect with a third column being installed:
[image]

**Why am I unable to create equal width columns in the nested main container? Shouldn't my grid be equally split in half if I put two fr units for grid-template-columns?**

Everything was working perfectly until I applied grid to the nested main container.

**And why are my grid-items jumbled up like this at the bottom of the screen?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are giving grid-areas to your elements withing your main grid, without actually using the grid-area property on main. I've removed these in the snippet and the main grid displays with 2 equal columns:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
  border: 1px red solid;
}

.header {
  background-color: purple;
  grid-area: header;
}

.side-navigation {
  background-color: orange;
  grid-area: side-navigation;
}

.main {
  background-color: grey;
  grid-area: main;
}

.search {}

.traffic {}

.daily-traffic {}

.mobile-users {}

.social-stats {}

.new-members {}

.recent-activity {}

.message-user {}

.settings {}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 80px 80px 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "header" "side-navigation" "main";
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
  body {
    grid-template-columns: 80px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "header header" "side-navigation main"
  }
  .main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="side-navigation">Side Navigation</div>

  <main class="main">
    <div class="item search">Search</div>
    <div class="item traffic">Traffic</div>
    <div class="item daily-traffic">Daily Traffic </div>
    <div class="item mobile-users">Mobile Users</div>
    <div class="item social-stats">Social Stats</div>
    <div class="item new-members">New Members</div>
    <div class="item recent-activity">Recent Activity</div>
    <div class="item message-user">Message User</div>
    <div class="item settings">Settings</div>
  </main>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Ohh you're saying I didn't use grid-area-template on main and I had labelled the elements inside main with grid area.

Comment: Yes, you needed to state the grid-template-areas property for your parent element (main) if you are using grid-area in your child elements.

Answer (score 2):

I think it has to do with all of the `grid-area:` labels with no `grid-template-areas:` rule to define where they go. I just checked your code in dev tools and when i removed those `grid-area:` labels it became a 2 column grid.

add a grid-template-areas for .main

```
.main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: 150px;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "search          traffic"
      "daily-traffic   mobile-users"
      "social-stats    new-members"
      "recent-activity message-user"
      "settings        ............";
}
```

all extra(more than 1) white space in grid-template-areas is ignored so you can add extra spaces to align your columns. Also, notice the '.' at the end you use '.' or multiple(like the white space extra just gets ignored) to signify leaving that cell empty. the whole thing breaks if you remove those periods at the end, every cell must be accounted for in your grid-template-areas.

Rachel Andrew has a lot of great material on CSS grid.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RssSS_xhv2E

Comment: Okay so basically you’re saying that because I used the grid-area-template format on body, I need to be consistent and use it on the nested grid container as well right?

Comment: You need to be consistent per grid context. grid-area and grid-template-areas work together. you can't have one without the other. if you just have grid-area without a grid-template-areas grid doesn't know where you want to put each element. If you want to remove the grid-area labels on all the divs inside of main you won't need grid-template-areas and auto placement will just lay them out in the order of source code. You could use line placement to lay them out. The fact that you used grid-temp-area on the body doesn't mean you have to use them in .main they are two separate grid contexts.